# How do I recieve the time from a TimePicker and put it into a variable?

Tags: java, android-studio

**I strongly appreciate any and all help I can get**

*API 21*

1)My timePicker (named **timeSelector**) is supposed to be interacted with

2)Then when the button is clicked it is supposed to take the **timeSelector's** hour and minute into two variables.

However, I am really struggling with it, which is frustrating because it seems relatively straightforward.

Sources I Have Looked At:

- ### https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentMinute()

  ### [Android API 21 - TimePicker widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926727/android-api-21-timepicker-widget)

  [android alarm app using timepicker to select time and intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798459/android-alarm-app-using-timepicker-to-select-time-and-intents)

My code:

> ```
>   TimePicker myPick =(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeSelector);
>     int myhour = myPick.getCurrentHour();
>     int myminute = myPick.getCurrentMinute();
> ```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7xmj.png)

> I really wanna thank everyone that helps me out in advance. I'm confident that as I learn and practice more that this amateur will become a pro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the import statement for `TimePicker` class to `android.widget.TimePicker`, it looks like you have a class with the same name in your project.

Comment: You sir, are a saint.